# Team foundation server - update existing review comments

Tags: tfs

I saw this code in other post, however, It does not provide an example of how to update an existing comment. does anyone has an example of how to do that.

```
public List<CodeReviewComment> GetCodeReviewComments(int workItemId)
{
    List<CodeReviewComment> comments = new List<CodeReviewComment>();

    Uri uri = new Uri(URL_TO_TFS_COLLECTION);
    TeamFoundationDiscussionService service = new TeamFoundationDiscussionService();
    service.Initialize(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri));
    IDiscussionManager discussionManager = service.CreateDiscussionManager();

    IAsyncResult result = discussionManager.BeginQueryByCodeReviewRequest(workItemId, QueryStoreOptions.ServerAndLocal, new AsyncCallback(CallCompletedCallback), null);
    var output = discussionManager.EndQueryByCodeReviewRequest(result);

    foreach (DiscussionThread thread in output)
    {
        if (thread.RootComment != null)
        {
            CodeReviewComment comment = new CodeReviewComment();
            comment.Author = thread.RootComment.Author.DisplayName;
            comment.Comment = thread.RootComment.Content;
            comment.PublishDate = thread.RootComment.PublishedDate.ToShortDateString();
            comment.ItemName = thread.ItemPath;
            comments.Add(comment);
        }
    }

    return comments;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code review comments which are published are not support to edit/change. The code snip above could help you get all code review comments from the codereviewrequest workitem's id.

When you want to set a new code review comment for this [DisscussionThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.discussionthread%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) using the method below, you will get an error message "***The property 'Content' cannot be changed because the discussion or comment has been published***."

```
  thread.RootComment.Content = "New Comment";
```

Here is an user voice that you could vote: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18698392-change-code-review-comments